# how can i install and use eclipse for java development in hp chromebook

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome-os

Actually there is no enough storage to install eclipse in my hp chrome book. Only 8 GB memory space is remaining and also I couldn't find the way to download and install eclipse for chrome OS.Is there anyone who can help me downloading and installing eclipse for java development in hp chrome book without any performance issues?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418183/eclipse-for-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to do.

**Turn on Linux Apps in Chrome OS**

1. Open the settings of your Chromebook
2. Click on the "Advanced" option in the left panel
3. Click on the "Developers" option
4. Turn on Linux Apps.

Reference:
[How to turn on Linux Apps in Chrome OS 90 and newer on a Chromebook](https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2021/04/how-to-turn-on-linux-apps-in-chrome-os.html)

**Install Eclipse IDE**

Use the following commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/oldsources.list
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo echo deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libnss3 menulibre default-jdk
wget https://apprepo.de/appimage/download/eclipse-jdt
chmod 755 Eclipse-JDT.AppImage
./Eclipse-JDT.AppImage
menulibre
```

Reference:
[How to install Eclipse IDE on a Chromebook](https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2021/03/how-to-install-eclipse-ide-on-chromebook.html)